# What's the elemental form used in conjuring a super power/ability?

Tags: super-powers, energy, abilities, balancing-magic-systems, energy-beings

Example: kinetic energy used for psychic abilities and chakra for ninjas and so on. What more forms are there? 
If a knight(mage/magical knight) were to use his 'superpowers', what form of energy could he intake? 
There are several humanoid forms of energies that sustain abilities, what could they be..?
Telekinesis, cyrokinesis...etc all kinetic energy.
Likewise, aren't there more specific energy types, say, like spiritual energy?

Comment: This is Too Broad and Primarily Opinion-based.  To fix TB, focus on a specific power or ability.  To fix POB, provide objective criteria by which answers could be evaluated.  As is, we could pick any power or ability and argue based on our own opinions that it should be provided by any elemental form we choose.

Comment: Aren't they all just human inventions?  Spiritual energy, sexual energy, divine energy, celestial energy etc.  You can make up whatever rocks your fiction.

Comment: Why would cryokinesis be tied to kinetic energy? It's about moving *coldness*. Well, according to the linguistic roots of the word - I don't know what cryokinesis does in your world. Which brings me to everything else - there isn't "an energy" one uses with superpowers because superpowers don't exist. Each piece of fiction interprets them differently. If at all.

Comment: Please consult the [help] and take the [tour] to better understand our standards.